# Connecting NVIDIA RTX GeForce 4090 to Ubuntu 22.04 in VM

Tags: virtualization, gpu, nvidia-geforce

I have a Lenovo Legion 7 that I am not using for gaming. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in Hyper-V and want the NVIDIA GPU (RTX GeForce 4090 ) provide compute power for apps run under Ubuntu. After installing NVIDIA drivers, I saw that the Ubuntu guest OS doesn't see the GPU.
According to some sources the GPU doesn't attach to the VM. There are a few techniques recommended to attach the GPU to the VM. GPU passthru looks promising but is it reliable.
There is also something called GPU partitioning that appears to allow assignment to some of the GPU's processors to the guest OS.

Is there a reliable step-by-step plan to attach the GPU to the guest OS in a VM ?

Comment: This is not a question on Ubunut, it's a question on how to configure Hyper-V to pass through the GPU. Please raise the question in a forum dedicated to Windows and Hyper-V support.

Comment: Actually it involves NVIDIA, WIndows 11 Powershell and Ubuntu since ultimately the GPU needs to be connected to the VM (which is running Ubuntu)